# sort an array in decreasing order of frequency and no duplicate, in o(n)

Tags: sorting, duplicates, time-complexity, frequency

I have an array of integers in the range of{1....n}, and i
 need to give an O(n) algorithm
that gets rid of duplicate numbers, and sorts the elements of the array
in decreasing order of frequency, starting with the element that appears
the most.

I thought of radix sort or some version of counting sort, but can't figure out how to do it in o(n).
Thank you for your help

Comment: There are no o(n) sorting algorithms.

Comment: you can sort an algorithm in o(n) with counting sort, radix sort or bucket sort  in most cases(depend on your array)

Comment: They are not O(n).

Comment: @RoboRobok [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) is linear in the number of elements and the range of them. The author specificly asks about a case where the range and the number of elements is identical. (Yes, you could argue it's logn to read the elements themselves, but that's getting to the point where we are in philosophy that is simply not practical and not interesting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, one possible solution:

First, count all elements (first step of counting sort), and create a histogram, where `count[i] = #times i appeared`. This is `O(n)`.

Then, create a second array `(frequency, i)` after all duplicates are removed. This is `O(n)`.

Last, do a counting sort on the new array, compare by frequency, and output the value. This is `O(n)`.

Comment: can you elaborate on the second array? 
i didn't understand how to create the array

Comment: An array of tuple/structs/pairs, (depending on  the language), where each element has both the frequency of each number and the number itself.